# Uncaught type error $(...)textillate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering if anyone else has had a problem with the textillate function bringing this error up in the javascript console.

I checked my source code and my files are linked correctly and I'm using a demo from another site but I'm stuck with this error still

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tlt').textillate({
       in: {
           shuffle: false,
           sync: true
       },
       out: {
             effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
             shuffle: false,
             sync: true
       },
       loop: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.vusive.com/v2/plugins/textillate/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.vusive.com/v2/plugins/textillate/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="demo">
    <p>Each of this letter will animate.</p>
</div>
```

If you go to full screen mode to test the code then open up the developer console, you will see the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not include the `textillate` JavaScript file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('p').textillate({
       in: {
           shuffle: false,
           sync: true
       },
       out: {
             effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
             shuffle: false,
             sync: true
       },
       loop: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.vusive.com/v2/plugins/textillate/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/textillate/jquery.textillate.js"></script>

<link href="https://www.vusive.com/v2/plugins/textillate/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="demo">
    <p>Each of this letter will animate.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know I did not link that file but the documentation said only the animate.css and jquery.textille.js were required.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include jquery.textillate.js file. Please add something like this after including jquery.lettering.js file,

```
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/textillate/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, their documentation didn't mention needing to link that file so I didn't bother to but it seems I need it.

Comment: Got information from this link http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/animate-text-textillatejs/. Glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have the wrong file or wrong plugin name.

The url to file `jquery.lettering.js` you have can easily be opened in browser.

The plugin function contained is: `$.fn.lettering` not `$.fn.textillate` as you are using

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the plugin and it seems that `textillate` isn't a jQuery function. There is `lettering` though.

Maybe try

```
$('.tlt').lettering({ ... })
```

The function inside the plugin

```
$.fn.lettering = function( method ) { ... });
```